# VBA compile error: Variable not defined ( JSON )

Tags: json, vba

I'm running a test code and edited for my needs. When I try to run it I get an error with JSON highlighted `Compile error: Variable not defined`. The code was taken from this post: [Import data from an API link that contains JSON to EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623127/import-data-from-an-api-link-that-contains-json-to-excel/51624048#51624048) so it should be a valid code. I already have `JsonConverter` module imported and `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` reference added.

Edit: I am using `VBA-JSON v2.3.1` and also updated `VBA-UTC v.1.0.6`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()
    Dim vResult
    Dim sName
    Dim authKey As String
    authKey = "my_auth_key"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://my_site_url", True
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & authKey
        .send
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid JSON"
        End
    End If
    vResult = vJSON("data")
    JSON.ToArray vResult, aData, aHeader
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    vJSON.Remove "data"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Do Until .Count = 1
            .Item(.Count).Delete
        Loop
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    For Each sName In vJSON
        If IsArray(vJSON(sName)) Or IsObject(vJSON(sName)) Then
            JSON.ToArray vJSON(sName), aData, aHeader
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add 
                OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
                Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
                .Columns.AutoFit
            End With
            vJSON.Remove sName
        End If
    Next
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add 
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    JSON.Flatten vJSON, vResult
    JSON.ToArray vResult, aData, aHeader
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add 
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `JSON` in your code? When you imported the JSON.bas module [as instructed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51624048/11683), did you make sure it is named `JSON` in your project?

Comment: You should really only need the one json parser. Your code is for VBA-JSON-parser so why not just have that and ensure imported correctly as per comment above.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out now. I had `JsonConverter` imported not JSON.bas as instructed. For some reason I thought they'd do the same thing. Last thing to figure our would be how I could make the first row from this pulled data ( ex . `worker_id`, `first_name` etc ) to show automatically as filterable.